# My data from web can't save as excel by using DataFrame

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, web-crawler

I use API to get the data from the web, and I  successfully get the data!I want to save these data in an excel.But there must be some mistakes that I can't save!Also, there isn't a Error.Can anyone tell me how to fix it?Thanks!Wish you a good life!
Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
Function_code=[input("請輸入所需代碼")]
Year_of_start_time=str(eval(input("請輸入開始年份")))
Month_of_start_time=str(eval(input("請輸入開始月份")))
Year_of_end_time=str(eval(input("請輸入結束年份")))
Month_of_end_time=str(eval(input("請輸入結束月份")))
Demension:[]

url="https://nstatdb.dgbas.gov.tw/dgbasAll/webMain.aspx?sdmx/"
if Function_code==["A11010208010"]:
    Dimension="1+2.1+2+3+4..M"
elif Function_code==["A093102020"]:
    Dimension=".1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16..M"
elif Function_code==["A018203010"]:
    Dimension="1+2+3.1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10+11+12+13+14+15+16+17+18+19+20..M"
elif Function_code==["A093005010"]:
    Dimension="1+2+3.1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8..M"
Function_code=str(Function_code)

r=requests.get(url+Function_code+"/"+Dimension+"&"+"startTime="+Year_of_start_time+"-"+Month_of_start_time+"&"+"endTime="+Year_of_end_time+"-"+Month_of_end_time)
print(r.text)

import json
import pandas as pd
import csv

list_of_dicts=r.json()
print(type(r))
print(type(list_of_dicts))
import json
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts)

df.to_excel('list_of_dicts.xlsx')
```

I wants save those data, which I craw  from the web, into a excel.
btw, these data are 3-dimension.

Comment: can you provide sample of **list_of_dicts** ?

Comment: [`eval` really is dangerous](https://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html), use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead if truly needed. However, it is not in this case - since you're looking for a string, just use the output of `input()`.